# How does one interpret the factor ring of a factor ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

If I have $\phi: R/I \rightarrow A$ as a ring map, how can I interpret $(R/I)/\ker(\phi) \cong A$?  It seems pretty easy, but I just can't wrap my brain around it this morning.

Comment: Is $\phi$ surjective ?

Answer (score 4):

This is one of the isomorphism theorems: Ideals of $R/I$ have the form $J/I$ for some ideal $J$ of $R$ containing $I$, and there is a unique isomorphism $(R/I)/(J/I) \cong R/J$ of $R$-algebras. Thus, quotient rings of quotient rings of $R$ are quotient rings of $R$. The terminology "factor ring" is unfortunate and old-fashioned.